# Split function SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column with strings inside. I would like to split them into 3 new columns and drop the original after doing so.

```
\[{"richResultType": "Breadcrumbs", "items": \[{"name": "Unnamed item"}\]}, {"richResultType": "FAQ", "items": \[{"name": "Unnamed item"}\]}, {"richResultType": "Product snippets", "items": \[{"name": "Elevate Vaillant Langarmhemd", "issues": \[{"issueMessage": "Missing field \\"aggregateRating\\"", "severity": "WARNING"}, {"issueMessage": "Missing field \\"review\\"", "severity": "WARNING"}, {"issueMessage": "Missing field \\"highPrice\\"", "severity": "WARNING"}\]}\]}\]
```

I tried using split

```
select split_part('richResultType', ' ', 1) || ' ' || split_part('richResultType', ' ', 2)
```

but it was only returning the first part **richResultType**

I was expecting this as end results :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
rich_result_type(Col1)         Items (Col2)                Issues (Col3)
Breadcrumbs                   Unnamed item                 aggregateRating
FAQ                           Elevate Vaillant             review
Product snippets                                           highPrice
...                ...                       ...
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (sql server, mysql, oracle, postgres, redshift, snowflake, etc). This looks like JSON data, so your best option (depending on your RDBMS) is to hit it with JSON functions.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: I am using snowflake

Comment: split_part is a string function, and you are concatenating strings.  are you trying to extract values from a JSON string using string splitting?

Comment: @Kurt the data was stored in snowflake and l thought with split_part l could split and extract values but it did not work hence l asked for help . I am still new to data world hence this confusion and learning .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is a JSON string, so it may already be stored in Snowflake as a variant type. If it is not, you can convert it to a variant using the parse_json function:

```
create or replace table T1(s string);

insert into T1 select $$[{"richResultType": "Breadcrumbs", "items": [{"name": "Unnamed item"}]}, {"richResultType": "FAQ", "items": [{"name": "Unnamed item"}]}, {"richResultType": "Product snippets", "items": [{"name": "Elevate Vaillant Langarmhemd", "issues": [{"issueMessage": "Missing field \"aggregateRating\"", "severity": "WARNING"}, {"issueMessage": "Missing field \"review\"", "severity": "WARNING"}, {"issueMessage": "Missing field \"highPrice\"", "severity": "WARNING"}]}]}]$$;

select   VALUE:richResultType::string
        ,VALUE:items::array
        ,*
from T1, table(flatten(parse_json(s)));
```

You can then see from the sample SQL how to extract the parts you want. Since the "items" is an array, it doesn't lend itself well to being put into columns the way the output is showing. You can read the first member in the array using VALUE:items[0], but I think you may need to do some more flattening/processing.